# I can't change quantity for multiple products at once, using admin products listing page

Tags: product, product-attribute, inventory, quantity

I want to change quantity for 20 or so products at once, from the admin products listing page. The products are of type Configurable. I select the products, and choose "Update attributes" in the Action dropdown, and then click Submit. On the next page I should be able to change some of the settings (one of which is quantity - in the Inventory section) for this group of products. When I change the quantity here, the quantity stays unchanged for some reason, on the admin products listing, even though Magento says everything has been saved correctly. What am I missing here?

Comment: Configruable products dont have quantity themself.